# is tor still vulnerable to replay attack?

Tags: attacks

I'm doing a project to my University that consist studiyng vulnerabilities on TOR network. One attack I came across on Intenet is the "replay attack". This type of attack allows a adversary, that controls Entry Node and some Extit node, duplicate cells to raise duplicate errores on Exit Node.

My question is simple (but I didn't finde info on Internet): is this attack still efective on TOR? or is there a patch that fixed it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

trac.torproject.org is the official Tor wiki and bug management site. I found this:

https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/14038

> ScrambleSuit uses Uniform Diffie-Hellman as one of its authentication
>   mechanisms. To defend against replay attacks, a sever caches the HMAC
>   of a client's authentication message. The attack works as follows. In
>   the first step, an active adversary (e.g., a censor trying to detect
>   ScrambleSuit) observes a client authenticate successfully towards a
>   ScrambleSuit server and captures the server's Uniform Diffie-Hellman
>   response. In the second step, the adversary replays the captured
>   response to the very same server. Since the server did not cache the
>   HMAC of its own response, it will interpret the replayed data as
>   legitimate authentication message of a new client and respond with an
>   authentication response. The adversary now successfully tricked the
>   server into responding despite not knowing the shared secret. This
>   creates a noteworthy distinguisher which can help identifying
>   ScrambleSuit. Luckily, it's easy to fix this problem. Introducing
>   message types would be one option but it would break backwards
>   compatibility. The easiest fix which retains backwards compatibility
>   is to make the server also cache its own HMACs which are part of the
>   response to a client's authentication message. The downside is that it
>   doubles the size of the replay table but that's tolerable. Note that
>   obfs4 is not affected by this problem because a client's and a
>   server's authentication message are different. A patch follows in a
>   minute.